# Efficiently split a point cloud into two parts by a hyperplane to maximize the total sum of values associated with one part

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computational-geometry, approximation, discrete-mathematics

I have the following problem in mind. Suppose we have an $n$-dimensional point cloud with $m$ points. Each point in the cloud is associated with a value $X_i,1\leq i\leq m$. I would like to use a hyperplane to partition this point cloud into two parts, $S$ and $S^c$, in order to maximize $\sum_{i\in S} X_i$. Are there any efficient ways to do it?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. If this cannot be solved efficiently, do there exist a good approximation algorithm?

Comment: Presumably there aren't any bounds on the values of $X_i$? For example, a heavy positive point must be in $S$ and a heavy negative point must be in $S^c$?

Comment: 1. Are the values all non-negative?  Or can they be negative?  2. Is $m$ potentially larger than $n$?  3. What approaches have you considered?  You might want to look into soft-margin SVM and how it finds a linear separating hyperplane.

Comment: @JaredGoguen There could be good bounds on $X_i$, for example, we know that it lies between [-3,3]. But there is no additional information..

Comment: @D.W. Some values are positive and some values are negative. In general, $m$ is much bigger than $n$, and $n$ is usually not very big (as most 200). I indeed have tried to look at soft-margin SVM, but it gives me no clue on how good that solution might be compared to the optimal solution of the original problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The special case of your problem in which the points are in $\{-1,1\}^n$ and the values are $\pm 1$ is known as *Maximum Agreement for Halfspaces*. When talking about approximation, we want a positive objective function, and in this case it is convenient to ask for the number of correctly classified points. A point is correctly classified if either its value is $+1$ and it belongs to $S$, or its value is $-1$ and it belongs to $S^c$.

A trivial $1/2$-approximation algorithm just picks any halfspace and chooses either the halfspace or its complement. One of these satisfies at least half the constraints. [Guruswami and Raghavendra](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~prasad/Files/halfspace.pdf) showed that no better polynomial time approximation algorithm exists unless $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$.

In practice you might be able to use some heuristics, but these of course don't provide any guarantees in the worst case.